# Changing javascript to jQuery first time Struts 1.3 application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jsdt

I am changing the javascript in my project to jquery. This is the first time im using Jquery and expect me to be making silly mistakes please.
I placed a simple JQ alert function in a .js file which looks like below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#stt").change(function(){
    alert("hi");
  });
});
```

So the aim is to throw an alert msg when the value of a td element with id="stt" is changed.

```
<tr id="stttr"> 
<td id="stt"> <html:text property="stt" size="20" maxlength="20"  style="height:12px; width: 180px;" /></td></tr>
```

and this is how im referencing jquery between the head tags of the jsp.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/SearchPanelJQ.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/CalendarPopup.js"></script>
```

The Calendarpop.js is an older javascript file which i dont want to replace (it works fine on all browsers). 
Now when i visit this page in a browser with script debugging enabled in IE, i get the following error .

```
HTML1201: localhost is a website you've added to Compatibility View. 
ReportingTemplate.jsp
SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not     applied to :visited. 
ReportingTemplate.jsp
SCRIPT5007: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object 
SearchPanelJQ.js, line 1 character 1
```

The last line tells me something is not right with the setup. Can you tell me what?

I installed the jsdt jquery plugin and am using JQ v1.9.
The project is a struts project.

Edit: 
1) It works when the JQ function is included in the jsp. it dosent work when its in a different .js file.
2) even if i include http:in the reference, it only works when the document.ready function is in the same JSP and not when it is in a different .js file. This beats the purpose as the same validations will be used in multiple pages in my project.

Comment: The error you are getting says you haven't included jquery properly. Are you running the page from your desktop rather than a webserver?

Comment: Im running it on tomcat server and using eclipse ide.

Comment: Are your scripts tags exactly as you have them in your question? if they are, then the error you are getting isn't possible if you're running from a webserver and have access to `ajax.googleapis.com`

Comment: Yes sir. They are exactly as mentioned. However, could it be because of the  jsdt jquery plugin

Comment: Not if your scripts are in the exact order that you have above.

Answer (score 2):

for future reference:

- Run in Chrome (or any browser as other users have pointed out)
- Right click > Inspect Element > Console
- Read error logs (Console can provide js, php, and other errors to help pinpoint specific lines where the malfunction is happening)

Your

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

should be

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The reason, provided by **user2736012** is:

OP is using a "protocol relative" url, which automatically uses the protocol that was used for fetching the page. In this case, if the protocol is `file://home/User/Desktop/foo.html`, the protocol relative url becomes `file://ajax.googlapis...`, which of course won't work. But it'll work when fetching the page using http, because it'll then be `http://ajax.googleapis...`

Comment: Only because OP is likely loading from `file:`. Otherwise the `src="//ajax.googleapis..."` is usually fine.

Comment: there is console in all 5 major browsers nowadays.

Comment: Yeah, an explanation of why this is the case would help the OP not make the same mistake again.

Comment: @Archer I am actually unsure as to when/why // used, I suggested my change because I noticed his set-up is different than what works for me for jquery "set-up" both locally and hosted online.

Comment: OP is using a "protocol relative" url, which automatically uses the protocol that was used for fetching the page. In this case, if the protocol is `file://home/User/Desktop/foo.html`, the protocol relative url becomes `file://ajax.googlapis...`, which of course won't work. But it'll work when fetching the page using `http`, because it'll then be `http://ajax.googleapis...`.

Comment: @user2736012 Thank you. I knew it will work. But you told me the reason why.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I am referencing JQ version 1.9 because i read in a tutorial that it should automatically pick the latest version in the 1.9 series. It works if i change it to 1.9.0 or 1.9.1. However, i still dont understand why 1.9 didnt work. it should have picked the latest 1.9.* version.

But atleast by making it 1.9.1/0 it works from a .js file.

Answer (score 0):

the link for library is right, check it [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)!
look at this line

```
SCRIPT5007: The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object 
SearchPanelJQ.js, line 1 character 1
```

Something wrong with this library or conflict occurred.

Comment: it works when the document.ready function is in the jsp's head tags. but not when its in a different .js file. So the library should be fine dont u think?